# SAP UI table column child data

Tags: sapui5

In table on column there is ObjectIdentifier.

In this I want catch column data and how can update it.

How can I access table -- > column ---- > ObjectIdentifier -- > text data property?

```
     <ObjectIdentifier title="{Name}" text="{ProductId}" class="sapMTableContentMargin" />

      var tab= this.getView().byId("idProductsTable");
      col=tab.getColumns()[0];
```

What is next ?

Please help.

Comment: You can't, the `ObjectIdentifier` has no editable counterpart. You should either create your own form to change the `title` and/or `text` property in your model, or -- instead of a single column `ObjectIdentifier` -- use two columns with `Input` (`editable=true/false`) to change the values inline

Comment: Hi MIT, i saw you posted some questions regarding how to access table column and update data. The best practice is not to access the UI directly to update data instead you should update data model.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion 
basically I just want child object of column for view hide/show functionality. there are 2 views in one view I have to hide Product id from column and in one view both product and product id are display. 

and here both data is in one column I am trying to access child byID but getting it as undefined.

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview

console.log(" >> ",tab.getColumns()[0].byId("productID").getProperty("visible"));

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to figure out exactly what you want, so I'm going to take a guess. If you have other requirements I encourage you to edit your question or ask a new one, not add requirements or explanations in the comments.

You want to access the text property of the ObjectIdentifiers in a Table.

Following the column route as you're doing in your question won't get you very far. Instead, you want the Table's items aggregation, and from there, an item's cells aggregation. Here's a screenshot of how to get that based on the [Table - Columns sample in the OpenUI5 Explored app](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.Table/preview):

[image: getting the text of the ObjectIdentifier on the first row of a table]

As far as hiding information, you can either make the whole ObjectIdentifier invisible (visibility here is at a control level):

`t.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].setVisible(false)`

or you must set the value of the text property appropriately:

`t.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].setText()`

Comment: yes u catch the right but further if I want to hide/Show Title or Text
is not posible.... 

t.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].getTitle().setVisible(false)

t.getItems()[0].getCells()[0].getText().setVisible(false)

basically I have to hide prodctid in one view.

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect this further requirement. Please make sure you update your question to reflect it too.